# Android Dev Beginner here, trying to make button display Obama's face on ImageView

Tags: java, android, button, imageview, onclicklistener

### So the problem is... I can't seem to find out why the image wont show up when I click the button.

Also found this in the logcat (if it means anything):

```
01-04 12:05:43.032 21338-21345/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
```

Here is content_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
tools:context="com.example.dylan.secondapp.MainActivity"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:src="#00fe0000"
    android:layout_weight="0.25" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="174dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.43" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Okay Obama"
    android:id="@+id/obamabutton"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is MainActivity.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();

            //Testing out button changing image to obama
            addButtonClickListener();

        }
    });
}
public void addButtonClickListener()
{
    Button obamabutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.obamabutton);
    obamabutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ImageView obama = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            obama.setImageResource(R.drawable.obama);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put this:

```
Button obamabutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.obamabutton);
obamabutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ImageView obama = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        BitmapFactory.Options ops = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        ops.inSampleSize = 4;
        ops.inDither = false;
        ops.inMutable = true;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.obama, ops);
        obama.setImageBitmap(bitmap);;
    }
});
```

right after

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Explanation: Right now you are **specifying what should obamabutton do only when clicking on FAB**(setting obamabutton's clickListener in FAB's click event)

**EDIT:** to handle **OutOfMemoryError** try to use **updated code above**. This will make your image size 1/4 of original size.

Comment: Not exactly sure what FAB means?

Comment: FAB is simply Floatin Action Button. **FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);** As you see it is present in your java code but it's seems that it's **not** present in your layout anymore...

Comment: It seems if I move the code under 
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar); It crashes when i click on the button.

Comment: And what is the logcat output for this crash?

Comment: 01-04 13:46:46.811 25046-25046/com.example.dylan.secondapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.dylan.secondapp, PID: 25046
                                                                             java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 257291004 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 62MB until OOM

Comment: ^^ Thats after i click the button

Comment: Ah! The image was too big! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've updatet code above. In the answer. If this will help, set this as a correct answer please

Answer (score 0):

Try using set image drawable method as below 
     img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourimage)
   Drawable d =    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourimage)
    img.setImageDrawable(d);

Hope it helps!